# problem on slurm setting: network connection refused

Tags: slurm

I successfully completed setup slurm on 2 nodes.

And `scontrol show nodes`, `sinfo -a`, `srun -w <test_node> python test.py` gave me correct results.

I tried to modify some configuration related to GPUs so restarted `slurmctld` and `slurmd` on the master node.

Then it fails with the message below, from `slurmd -Dvvv`

```
slurmd: debug2: Error connecting slurm stream socket at 172.16.20.32:6817: Connection refused
slurmd: debug:  Failed to contact primary controller: Connection refused
```

from `slurmctld -Dvvv`

```
slurmctld: debug2: slurm_connect failed: Connection refused
slurmctld: debug2: Error connecting slurm stream socket at 172.16.20.32:6818: Connection refused
```

I tried to kill the process using `netstat -tulpn`and then retried. But it failed.

Why do I get this error?

These are config files.
`slurm.conf`

```
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
ClusterName=accelerate_fsdp
ControlMachine=fai033
ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
#SrunEpilog=
#SrunProlog=
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurmctld
#SwitchType=
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/affinity,task/cgroup

InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
#MessageTimeout=10
#ResvOverRun=0
MinJobAge=300
#OverTimeLimit=0
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
#UnkillableStepTimeout=60
#VSizeFactor=0
Waittime=0
#
#
# SCHEDULING
#DefMemPerCPU=0
#MaxMemPerCPU=0
#SchedulerTimeSlice=30
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_CORE
#
#

JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#JobCompUser=
#JobContainerType=
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
#JobAcctGatherType=
SlurmctldDebug=info
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=info
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES
GresTypes=gpu
NodeName=fai033 CPUs=32 RealMemory=362773 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=32 ThreadsPerCore=1 Gres=gpu:$gpuname$:4 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=fai032 CPUs=32 RealMemory=362773 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=32 ThreadsPerCore=1 Gres=gpu:$gpuname$:4 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

`gres.conf`

```
###gres.conf###
Nodename=fai033 Name=gpu Type=$gpuname$ File=/dev/nvidia[0-3]
Nodename=fai032 Name=gpu Type=$gpuname$ File=/dev/nvidia[0-3]
```

And these are messages from `systemctl status`

```
● slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/slurmd.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-11-24 18:17:19 KST; 7min ago
     Docs: man:slurmd(8)
 Main PID: 45262
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 9830)
   CGroup: /system.slice/slurmd.service

11월 24 18:17:19 fai033 systemd[1]: Starting Slurm node daemon...
11월 24 18:17:19 fai033 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
11월 24 18:17:19 fai033 systemd[1]: Started Slurm node daemon.
11월 24 18:17:35 fai033 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Supervising process 45262 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
```

```
● slurmctld.service - Slurm controller daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmctld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/slurmctld.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2023-11-24 18:20:33 KST; 4min 47s ago
     Docs: man:slurmctld(8)
 Main PID: 45875 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

11월 24 18:19:35 fai033 systemd[1]: Starting Slurm controller daemon...
11월 24 18:19:35 fai033 systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or direc
11월 24 18:19:35 fai033 systemd[1]: Started Slurm controller daemon.
11월 24 18:20:33 fai033 systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: New main PID 46109 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.
```

```
# /var/log
drwxr-xr-x   2 slurm     slurm               4096 11월 23 15:55 slurm-llnl/

# /var/spool
drwxr-xr-x  6 slurm  slurm 4096 11월 24 18:20 slurmctld/
drwxr-xr-x  2 slurm  slurm 4096 11월 24 18:20 slurmd/
```

And `/var/run/slurm-llnl` is getting deleted or the owner of the directory is being changed into `root`. Is it correct?